# spring controller as session scoped bean

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class SomeController {

        private CoreDataService coreDataService;
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeController.class);
        private SomeBusinessObject bo;
        private long activityId;
... 
}
```

Do anybody see any problem in making Spring Controler as session scoped bean?
So I am not convinced with this approach, but I am not able to justify why we should not do that. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

See this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667760/302387).

You can use a session scope for your controller if you want to hold instance variables. If you do have variables as shown in your code you need to ensure that you don't make the controller a singleton. This is because singletons are shared by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Session scope means your bean SomeController will be created instance for **each session.** The default scope is **singleton** which only be created one instance in spring container.